# Learning python from a book and need a little help here

Tags: python, eclipse, ubuntu, pydev

OK so I have this book
Violent Python - A Cookbook for Hackers, Forensic Analysts, Penetration Testers and Security Engineers.
I have gotten to page 10 and I'm a complete noob at this but it really fascinates me.

But this piece of code has me stumped:

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("192.168.95.148",21))
ans = s.recv(1024)
print ans
```

This is what I get in the console as a result:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

From what I can see the book says I should get this:

```
220 FreeFloat Ftp Server (Version 1.00).
```

Im using pydev and eclipse
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking us to aid you to learn how to perform a FTP DoS attack? If not, has the 192.168.95.148 a FTP server opened?

Comment: No I'm not wanting to perform an FTP DoS attack I'm just working through the book to get an understanding of the python language.

Comment: @gustavodidomenico Looks like it's just an exercise in retrieving FTP server information (type and version) using the `socket` module. How could this be considered DoS? I only see one connection.

Comment: I just asked a question, because the book title is a little weird for someone trying to learn python scripting. But not bad intentions here, stay sharp :)

Comment: And there are several exploits that can be used like that, in a very quickly research: http://exploitsdownload.com/search/FTP%20Server/.

Comment: @JamesPolland I really recommend a book designed for beginners if you   want to learn python itself.

Comment: stackoverflow isn't exactly ideal for very localized questions like this, perhaps resources like freenode's #python, reddits's r/learnpython, g+'s python community maybe a better choice.

Comment: Almost forgot, there are also "chat" rooms by subject located in the upper bar under the menu "chat".

Answer (score 4):

`s.connect(("192.168.95.148",21))` seems to try to connect to an FTP server on IP address 192.168.95.148. If you don't have an FTP server running on that IP, you will get a connection timeout error instead of a response from the FTP server. Do you have a FreeFloat FTP Server running on 192.168.95.148?

Comment: No I dont have an FTP server thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, that explains why you can't connect to it! :)

Comment: No probs thanks again I think I will skip that part of the book since I dont see any real outcome from it

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could try connecting to a known public FTP server? If the lack of a server is stopping you.
For example, ftp.mozilla.org